# Rails 3 Devise Session Has value but <% if user_signed_in? %> is false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I hope you can help, have been struggling with this one for a while now :|
Im using devise and Rails 3

When I click on Sign In, I get the devise Sign In page, I punch in the username and pw and click login.

After I clicked login I get redirected to the main page but now I still see the Sign In link, wich means that <% if user_signed_in? %> is still false. But it seems that there is some values in the session variable after I logged in, what is going on here? I have been using devise for some time and havent had any problems before. Thank guys!

---

**Before I logged in with devise**

```
<%= session %>
no value

<% if user_signed_in? %>
**is false**
```

---

**After I logged in with devise**

```
<%= session %>
_csrf_tokenAMUwVLu6G6rWfKICB43PYApFsYFRjVyJDSc2oU88uEk=warden.user.user.keyUser342$2a$10$.zslfggeUqvq.m/5LNSolOsession_id0db80c26bc36a4c1c74c223655dcb092

<% if user_signed_in? %>
**is false**
```

---

**EDIT:**

my routes.rb file

```
Cybercellar3::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  get "home/index"
```

```
<% if signed_in? %>
**is still false**
```

---

**EDIT2:**

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

      # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
      attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
    end
```

I think I found my problem in one of my controllers

application_controller.rb

```
    #facebook stuff
    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    end

    def signed_in?
        !!current_user
    end

    helper_method :current_user, :signed_in?

    def current_user=(user)
        @current_user = user
        session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
    #facebook stuff
```

after I removed this block it seemed to work perfectly :)

Comment: I always use `if current_user` :)

Comment: Same as kishie. I also, always endup checking for current_user. Is that available?

Answer (score 3):

Devise has a concept of "scopes" so that you can sign in multiple types of users simultaneously, e.g. an admin user and a regular user. To check if a user of *any* scope is signed in, use `signed_in?`. The scopes are defined by the naming of the model class and the `routes.rb` file. Be sure they match. Can you post both? To test this out you can also try an integration test.

Comment: Can you also post your user.rb file?

Answer (score 0):

I've also been having problems with this. It's funny because `user_signed_in?` is supposed to be more dependable than `current_user`, but this seems to indicate what I suspected -- that it's actually less dependable.

Let us know if someone finds something different.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, I have been struggling with the same issue and finally found a solution! It might not be your case, but still.

My problem occurred when I was switching from my simple hand-written authentication process to Devise. And the reason why current_user or user_signed_in? were all blank and false upon signing in was that I had similarly named methods (sign_in, current_user, etc) in my sessions_helper.rb file that remained from the old system, and these (old) methods were called from a brand new Devise controller instead of the right ones from the Devise lib.

So I just commented out all the methods in my old sessions helper that serve authentication process. And then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

As @Irina Nazarova said. Check to ensure that you don't have any methods my the same name you wrote yourself included in your project. It would seem Devise is using that first. This is what was causing my issue.